# Understanding of Squeeze Theorem with example

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f$ be a function satisfying $|f(x) − 3| ≤ 5$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 2$.
>   Find $\lim_{x\to 1} (x − 1)^2 f(x)$.

What I've done is the following:

$$-5 ≤ f(x) − 3 ≤ 5$$
$$-2 ≤ f(x) ≤ 8$$
$$-2(x-1)^2 ≤ (x-1)^2 f(x) ≤ 8(x-1)^2$$

By applying the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x\to1} -2(x-1)^2 = \lim_{x\to1} 8(x-1)^2 = 0$, the limit of $(x-1)^2 f(x)$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to1} (x-1)^2 f(x) = 0$.

**My question is what does the given range of $0≤x≤2$ does in this example, in the definition of the function and the use of Squeeze Theorem?**

Comment: The inequalities you have written are valid in the given range. And this given range is a neighborhood of the point $x=1$ so that you are allowed to take limits as $x\to 1$ on these inequalities via Squeeze theorem. If these inequalities were valid for the range $1.0001\leq x\leq 1.0002$ then you can't take limits $x\to 1$

Comment: You should see the precise statement of Squeeze theorem which says that the inequalities should hold in some neighborhood of a point $a$ (if we want to deal with limit as $x\to a$) except for the point $a$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you that $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $1$. Observe it is not required $f$ has any limit as $x\to 1$. Boundedness is enough.

Comment: In what case then does the inequality is required? I don't quite understand the meaning of boundedness.

Comment: If $f$ were unboundedn it could tend to infinity and we could arrive at indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$. By a squeeze theorem we could prove what follows: if one factor tends to zero while the 2nd factor is bounded, then the product tends to zero. Here we have a particular case of this lemma.